# How can I prevent hyphens causing text input to break in the Android Browser?

Tags: browser, input-methods, motorola-droid-pro

I have a Verizon Motorola Droid Pro (Android 2.3.3), and a persistent aggravation with the browser application.

Whenever typing in an input field and using a dash `-` that is adjacent to its preceding character, the next character I type is placed *before* the dash, and then the cursor placed before the dash. That is, assuming I'm trying to type `android-browser`:

1. I type `android-` At that moment, the cursor is correctly *after* the dash.
2. I type `b` The `b` is placed before the dash, and the cursor is now located after the `b`, before the dash. So if I kept typing I would end up with `androidbrowser-` with the cursor still before the dash.

This only happens in the Browser application, when I am inserting a dash that is adjacent to its preceding text. So if I were trying to type `android - browser` it would work fine. In order to get around this, I have to type `android-` and then manually move the cursor (although the end location is *exactly where it already is* at the end of the text!)

This happened before the Android system update a few months ago too, and I had hoped that the update would fix it... but, no dice!

I've considered that an alternate browser could be a solution, but I'd prefer to stick with the Android browser, I think.

Comment: Have you tried a different keyboard app?  Even though Droid Pro has a physical keyboard, alternate input methods may change its behavior.

Comment: I agree with Chahk, this sounds like an issue with the keyboard app that handles the software side, like auto-complete or spell corrections. Not to mention this device runs BLUR which has always been rather buggy.

Comment: @Chahk I'll look at that option some!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that, as noted in the comments, changing my keyboard app has solved this. I was having trouble with my default kb app going to 100% cpu when entering text lately, so that prompted me to try a new one, finally.

I have tried multiple times while typing this answer to get the behavior to occur again, and it won't. Yippee!